# Java: HashSet multiple types

Tags: java, hashset

I have a program that I have to use a HashSet for. My question arises from the fact that HashSets mainly contain one object, but if I wish to send information to the other class, it takes three objects: one string, one int, and one boolean.
The assignment says that I must use a HashSet

Constructor I am trying to send information to:

```
public Magic (String name, int size, boolean isVisible)
```

I have a class that is supposed to be sending sets of spells containing `name`, `size`, and `isVisible`.

Magic.go() class:

```
public void go()
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i < size) {
        if (isVisible == true) {
            System.out.println(name + "!");
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You only have one object type, namely `Magic`. So make it `Set<Magic>`.

Comment: Just make an object `Spell` that contains your three variables as fields: `name`, `size`, and `isVisible`.

Comment: @SqueezyMo When I try to add a new element to the HashSet (`spells.add("Test", 12, true);`), I get the error that `no suitable method found for add(java.lang.String,int,boolean)`.

Comment: You need to do `spells.add(new Magic("Test", 12, true));`

Comment: @River This allowed me to add them, but it doesn't seem to do anything. For example, when I call my go method that prints out `name`, changes the `size`, and checks whether it `isVisible`, it just returns my default values.

Comment: @WhyIsItReal just to be pedantic: you actually didn't ask a single question. You are just stating your problem.

Comment: @WhyIsItReal can you show us your `go` method?

Comment: `public void go()
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < size)
        {
            if (isVisible == true)
            {
                System.out.println(name+ "!");
            }
            i++;
        }
    }`

Answer (score 4):

Just create an object which contains all the three fields like this:

```
import java.util.Objects;

public class NameSizeVisible {
    private final String name;
    private final int size;
    private final boolean isVisible;

    public NameSizeVisible(String name, int size, boolean isVisible) {
        this.name = name;
        this.size = size;
        this.isVisible = isVisible;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public boolean isVisible() {
        return isVisible;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(name,size,isVisible);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        NameSizeVisible other = (NameSizeVisible) obj;
        if (isVisible != other.isVisible)
            return false;
        if (!Objects.equals(name, other.name))
            return false;
        if (size != other.size)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Override is a way where you flag that the method you are implementing exists in a class you inherit from. in this case from Object.

Comment: @WhyIsItReal so you're able to compare these Magic objects for equality if need be.

Comment: You (almost always) need to override the `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods for objects that you put in a `HashSet`.

Comment: The hashCode method could be shortened to one line:  `return Objects.hash(name, size, isVisible);`.

Answer (score -2):

You can use a HashSet that stores Objects. So you would have:

```
HashSet<Object> set = new HashSet<>();
set.add(name);
set.add(size);
set.add(isVisible);
```

Then when you access the objects  you just need to cast them to their respective types:

```
String name = "";
int size = 0;
boolean isVisible = false;

for (Object o : set) {
    if (o instanceof String) {
        name = (String) o;
    } else if (o instanceof int) {
        size = (int) o;
    } else {
        isVisible = (boolean) o;
    }
}
```

Comment: As a rule of thumb, if you are using instanceof , you either have to hide it behind a method (because of some limitation in design) or you need to change your design to use OO

Comment: Yes but she said she needs to add those 3 variables to a set that is then passed to the magic object. Based on the limitations of only being able to use a HashSet for that, there aren't many great ways